# How can I implement per-project appSettings and global appSettings across multiple Visual Studio projects?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-config, configuration-management

I've got multiple projects in a Visual Studio solution and I've got some settings which are project-specific and others which are global.  Configuration file wise I want to accomplish the following:

- Be able to reuse the common/global settings across all projects by externalizing a global settings file
- Have project-specific configuration settings (no problems there)
- Have project-specific configuration secrets which are externalized into separate files and outside of the working directory

My plan was to use the ability of the file attribute in `<appSettings file="...">` to merge in the per-project and global settings as follows:

WebProject1's `web.config`:

```
  <appSettings file="WebProject1.config">
    <add key="WebProject1Setting1" value="WebProject 1 Setting 1" />
  </appSettings>
```

`WebProject1.config`:

```
  <appSettings file="Global.config">
    <add key="WebProject1Secret1" value="WebProject 1 Secret 1" />
  </appSettings>
```

`Global.config`:

```
  <appSettings>
    <add key="GlobalSetting1" value="Global setting 1" />
  </appSettings>
```

Apparently however *only* the top level `web.config` can include another config file, as I get the following error on build:

> Unrecognized attribute 'file'. Note that attribute names are
>   case-sensitive.
>
> Source Error:

[image: Error]

My objective here was to define the settings that are common to all projects in `Global.config` and then define project-specific settings in the top level `web.config` files as well as in the included config files like `WebProject1.config`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot nest the inclusion of config files. ie. a web/app.config appsetting including another setting file which in turn including yet another setting file and so on. The file attribute on appsetting only works on main web/app.config file.

To achieve what you want you can use a separate section in web.config file of each project for secret settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>

<configSections>
<section name="SecretSettings" 
type="System.Configuration.NameValueFileSectionHandler, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"></section>
</configSections>

<SecretSettings configSource="secretsettings.config"></SecretSettings>

<startup>
<supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
</startup>
<appSettings>
</appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Now access your settings from program like

```
var secretSettings =(NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("SecretSettings");
```

Make sure the file secretsettings.config is set to copy always to output folder in its properties.

Comment: I reworded my question to better show my objectives.  Also, I was excited when I saw your answer because it addresses my problem exactly, except that I don't believe it's accurate.  Not only do the docs say only a single file can be specified but if I do include multiple settings files as you've done then neither work.

Comment: I have actually tried including multiple settings file and it worked perfectly  for me. I did it in console app however but that shouldn't make difference. The relative path however is created in two different way in console app vs web app. Here is an excerpt from official doc. "The path specified is relative to the main configuration file. For a Windows Forms application, this would be the binary folder (such as /bin/debug), not the location of the application configuration file. For Web Forms applications, the path is relative to the application root, where the web.config file is located."

Comment: Any way you could zip the solution and let me download?

Comment: After you mentioned the problem I went over the app and tried few other things. While web.config is correctly taking the settings from the last file even when I have provided multiple files, the settings from the first file are not reachable. This looks more like the forgiving syntax than a feature to include multiple files. Sorry about that.

Comment: Thanks Hem.  Any suggestions for me and what I'm trying to do?

Comment: I guess you can create a separate section like <SecretSettings configSource="secretsettings.config"></SecretSettings>.

Comment: Good idea. And then I'd access them as follows: `var testConfig1 = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager .GetSection("TestConfig1"); string testConfig1Key1 = testConfig1["TestConfig1Key1"]; string testConfig1Key2 = testConfig1["TestConfig1Key2"];`  If you want to turn your comment into an answer I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: I am updating the original answer to reflect this idea. There are some specific details about this way which I will be including.